# App::environment not being read correctly on Laravel 4.1

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-4, environment

I have two FB apps that I am using for local testing and production environments.  In order to have these run, I have a local environment set up and a production environment (default for Laravel).

I have set up the local environment in my bootstrap/start.php file:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('*Firstname*-*Lastname*-MacBook-Pro.local'),

));
```

I used the machine name of my laptop for my local environment (I am running it on MAMP).

Then in my Facebook OAuth2 Controller, I have:

```
public function getFacebook($provider) {      

        if(App::environment('local')) {
            return OAuth2::provider($provider, array('id' => 'appid1', 'secret' => 'appsecret1'));
        }
        else {
            return OAuth2::provider($provider, array('id' => 'appid2', 'secret' => 'appsecret2'));
        }

    }
```

However, when I run this on my local machine with MAMP, it is using appid2, appsecret2 (aka running the else and not reading the local environment).

I am missing something?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is `*Firstname*-*Lastname*-MacBook-Pro.local` your machine's hostname or is that the fake domain that you use to access your application?

Comment: I believe it's my machine's hostname.  When I go to system preferences and go to sharing, it says: Computers on your local network can access your computer at:
*Firstname*-*Lastname*-MacBook-Pro.local

Comment: Sorry, no clue. But I'd check the output of `hostname` and make sure it's the same as the one you put in the `start.php` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have entered the right name for your local machine. In fact you have entered the local domain name linked to your machine.

To know your machine's name, open a terminal and enter what is after the "@" sign. You can also run the command `cat /etc/hostname` from a terminal.

For me I have got `aaugusti@DellAntoine` so I'll enter `DellAntoine` as my local machine name.

Comment: I'm not seeing any "@" symbol in the terminal.  Each command line has:
Firstname-Lastname-MacBook-Pro:~ firstnamelastname$

Also, when typing cat /etc/hostname, I get the error: cat: /etc/hostname: No such file or directory

Comment: Also, typing "hostname", I get the output: Firstname-Lastnames-MacBook-Pro.local

Which I have set as the machine name in the bootstrap/start.php

Comment: I believe the issue here was that I need to perform a composer dump-autoload.  After performing the autoload, it seems like things are working as they should.